# How to pass a query from a form to a dropdown in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm using WP Job Manager to do this but I want to do a salary search from another page

https://wpjobmanager.com/document/tutorial-creating-custom-job-search-form/

this is the form, it uses a query string, it works with normal text boxes but with this Salary form I can't get it to work?

```
<div class="search_categories">
    <label for="search_categories"><?php _e( 'Salary', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></label>
    <select name="filter_by_salary" class="job-manager-filter">
        <option value=""><?php _e( 'Any Salary', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></option>
        <option value="upto20"><?php _e( 'Up to $20,000', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></option>
        <option value="20000-40000"><?php _e( '$20,000 to $40,000', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></option>
        <option value="40000-60000"><?php _e( '$40,000 to $60,000', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></option>
        <option value="over60"><?php _e( '$60,000+', 'wp-job-manager' ); ?></option>
    </select>
</div>
```